# Java Index out of bounds or code not entering If condition

Tags: java

I am writing a code for the following condition. Below are the two tables I am having.

**fff** table

```
start_date | holdings    |end_date  |
2022-09-09 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
2022-09-10 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
2022-09-12 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
2023-09-08 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
2022-09-09 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
2022-09-10 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
2022-09-12 | 1000        |08-08-2023|
```

**holdings** table

```
start_date | holder_name |
2022-09-09 | Pratik      |
2022-09-10 | Pratik      |
2022-09-12 | Sarvesh     |
```

I am trying to pass dates into a query wherein I am checking if the holder names are the same consecutively, some condition should be executed for the dates to be passed and if different, some condition should be executed. Following is the code I am writing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < filteredEndDate.size(); i++) {
                try {

                    BigDecimal sum = null;

                    for (int a = 0; a < tosstartDateList.size(); a++) {
                        if (filteredStartDate.get(i).equals(tosstartDateList.get(a))) {
                            if (restrictedHoldings.size() == 0) {
                                sum = (BigDecimal) rdsSession
                                        .createNativeQuery(DBQueries.GET_FLOAT_SHARES_BOTH_CONSOLIDATED_NON_CONSILIDATED)
                                        .setParameter("investmentId", investmentId, StringType.INSTANCE)
                                        .setParameter("startDate", filteredStartDate.get(0), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                        .setParameter("endDate", filteredEndDate.get(i), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                        .getSingleResult();
                                restrictedHoldings.add(sum.longValue());
                            } else {
                                //for (int k = 0; k < restrictedHoldings.size(); k++) {
                                    restrictedHoldings.add(restrictedHoldings.get(i - 1));
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    int count=0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.size(); j++) {
                        if (filteredStartDate.get(i).equals(listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j).getId().getStartDate())) {
                            //for (int b = 0; b < holderNames.size(); b++) {
                            if (i > 0 && listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j - 1).getHolderName().
                                    equals(listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j).getHolderName()))
                                sum = (BigDecimal) rdsSession
                                        .createNativeQuery(DBQueries.GET_FLOAT_SHARES_BOTH_CONSOLIDATED_NON_CONSILIDATED)
                                        .setParameter("investmentId", investmentId, StringType.INSTANCE)
                                        .setParameter("startDate", filteredStartDate.get(i), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                        .setParameter("endDate", filteredEndDate.get(i), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                        .getSingleResult();

                            else {
                                sum = (BigDecimal) rdsSession
                                        .createNativeQuery(DBQueries.GET_FLOAT_SHARES_BOTH_CONSOLIDATED_NON_CONSILIDATED)
                                        .setParameter("investmentId", investmentId, StringType.INSTANCE)
                                        .setParameter("startDate", filteredStartDate.get(0), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                        .setParameter("endDate", filteredEndDate.get(i), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                        .getSingleResult();

                            }
                            restrictedHoldings.add(sum.longValue());
                            count++;
                            //}



                        }

                        break;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The code is not entering inside if condition after the line

```
 if (filteredStartDate.get(i).equals(listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j).getId().getStartDate())) {
```

And if it enters, it is giving Index out of bounds at line

```
if (i > 0 && listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j - 1).getHolderName().
                                    equals(listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j).getHolderName()))
```

The size of both the tables does not match. The listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings represents holdings table and the filteredStartDate and filteredEndDate represent the date I am passing from the fff table.

Comment: "`i > 0 && listOfNonConsolidatedHoldings.get(j - 1)`" do you mean `i` rather than `j`? (Or `j` rather than `i`?)

Comment: "is not entering ... if it enters"???

Comment: If it enters it is giving Index out of bounds at one point

Answer (score 0):

The following code will iterate on *fff*, and attempt to match a *start_date* with a value in *holdings*.

You mention checking if the *holder* names are the same, that I'm not sure of, there only appears to be one *holder_name* column.

You'll have to adapt your code.
I'm using two *List<List<String>>* objects, *fff*, and *holdings*.

```java
String fffStartDate, fffHoldings, fffEndDate;
String holdingsStartDate, holdingsHolderName;
boolean found;
for (List<String> fffRow : fff) {
    fffStartDate = fffRow.get(0);
    fffHoldings = fffRow.get(1);
    fffEndDate = fffRow.get(2);
    found = false;
    for (List<String> holdingsRow : holdings) {
        holdingsStartDate = holdingsRow.get(0);
        holdingsHolderName = holdingsRow.get(1);
        if (fffStartDate.equals(holdingsStartDate)) {

            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have provided the whole code

Comment: Alright.  Now what is the relationship that is being iterated on.  If a date in _holdings_ appears in _fff_.  Or is it, if a date in _fff_ appears in _holdings_?

Comment: Date in fff appears in holdings